# SSO from internal website to office 365 account

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, office365

Can we use to the single sign-n (SSO) for signing in to the ms office services from my website/app, more importantly is it possible without ADFS(active directory federation services)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use your credentials on a website, but ADFS is a required option for SSO:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj631606.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You could also authenticate against Azure Active Directory- logging into Azure also logs you into O365. There are some useful instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151790.aspx).
Then you wouldn't need ADFS.